# How to never let npm install fail

Tags: node.js, jenkins, gruntjs, npm

I am using grunt and Jenkins to remote build my project.  Currently the "npm install" step can some times fail, and I would prefer the failure to be ignored, since some packages are only required for some types of builds.

The error showing is:

```
npm ERR! Error: No compatible version found:
...
npm ERR! System Linux 3.5.0-21-generic
npm ERR! node -v v0.11.2
npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.21
```

I am building on a linux box, and I have some plugins that only work on osx, but I do not need them to build the web target, and that is what I am trying to build now.

Is there a way to force nom to report ok, even if it can not finish the install?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best bet is probably to use `optionalDependencies` for these things ([npmjs docs](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/json.html#optionalDependencies)).

Modules listed in `optionalDependencies` will be loaded as if they were in the `dependencies` section, but if they fail they won't stop npm from proceeding with other actions.